Spring Retry @Recover is throwing an UndeclaredThrowableException?
My application has a primary and secondary source for data.
If the main method fails to retrieve data from the primary source, it fallback to the recover method and attempt to search in the secondary source.
If the data is also missing in the secondary source, I have it throw a custom exception.
However, it is being caught as an UndeclaredThrowableException instead of what's being thrown from the Recover method.
//After NotFoundInPrimaryException is thrown...

@Recover
private SearchResponseMapObject recover(SearchException e, String username) throws SearchException {
    try {
        searchService = searchServiceFactory.getSecondary();
        HashMap<String, Object> responseMap = searchService.getResponse(username); //throws NotFoundInSecondaryException
        SearchResponseMapObject secondaryResponseMapObject = processResponseMap(responseMap);

        return secondaryResponseMapObject;
    }
    catch (SearchException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public class SearchException extends Exception{...}
public class NotFoundInPrimaryException extends SearchException{...}
public class NotFoundInSecondaryException extends SearchException{...}

I've tried changing what types of Exception gets thrown and wrapping ex in a RuntimeException.
I was expecting the controller class to catch a SearchException instead of an UndeclaredThrowableException.
Tried following this existing question but could not solve my issue...
It mentions to add the exception to the throws clause even though it's already there.
Getting UndeclaredThrowableException instead of my own exception

The logic there in the RecoverAnnotationRecoveryHandler.recover() like this:
    T result = (T) ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(method, proxy, argsToUse);
    return result;

Where that ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod() does this:
    try {
        return method.invoke(target, args);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        handleReflectionException(ex);
    }

And, respectively:
public static void handleReflectionException(Exception ex) {
    if (ex instanceof NoSuchMethodException) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Method not found: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    if (ex instanceof IllegalAccessException) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not access method or field: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    if (ex instanceof InvocationTargetException invocationTargetException) {
        handleInvocationTargetException(invocationTargetException);
    }
    if (ex instanceof RuntimeException runtimeException) {
        throw runtimeException;
    }
    throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(ex);
}

So, if an exception thrown from your method is not a RuntimeException, it is definitely wrapped into an UndeclaredThrowableException.
Then the logic there in the RetryTemplate like this:
        if (doRecover) {
            try {
                T recovered = recoveryCallback.recover(context);
                context.setAttribute(RetryContext.RECOVERED, true);
                return recovered;
            }
            catch (UndeclaredThrowableException undeclaredThrowableException) {
                throw wrapIfNecessary(undeclaredThrowableException.getUndeclaredThrowable());
            }
        }

And:
    else if (throwable instanceof Exception) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E rethrow = (E) throwable;
        return rethrow;
    }

Here is a unit test which confirms that what you are talking about works as expected:
@SpringJUnitConfig
class So79106377Tests {

    @Autowired
    TestConfiguration testConfiguration;

    @Test
    void recovererRethrowsCustomCheckedException() {
        assertThatExceptionOfType(SearchException.class)
                .isThrownBy(this.testConfiguration::primary)
                .withMessage("Recover has failed");

        assertThat(this.testConfiguration.getPrimaryRetries().get()).isEqualTo(3);
        assertThat(this.testConfiguration.getRecoverCalled().get()).isTrue();
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableRetry
    static class TestConfiguration {

        AtomicInteger primaryRetries = new AtomicInteger();

        AtomicBoolean recoverCalled = new AtomicBoolean();

        @Retryable
        void primary() throws SearchException {
            this.primaryRetries.incrementAndGet();
            throw new NotFoundInPrimaryException("Not found in primary");
        }

        @Recover
        void recover() throws SearchException {
            this.recoverCalled.set(true);
            throw new SearchException("Recover has failed");
        }

        public AtomicInteger getPrimaryRetries() {
            return this.primaryRetries;
        }

        public AtomicBoolean getRecoverCalled() {
            return this.recoverCalled;
        }

    }

    static class SearchException extends Exception {

        public SearchException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }

    }

    static class NotFoundInPrimaryException extends SearchException {

        public NotFoundInPrimaryException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }

    }

}

The primary() and recover() both throws SearchException and the exception I verify in the unit test is exactly from that recover().
